# How to convert sparse matrix or theano.sparse to theano.tensor type?

Tags: python-3.x, pymc3

```
##importing the packages

import theano.sparse as ST 
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix 
import numpy as np 
import pymc3 as pm 
import theano as thno 
import theano.tensor as tt 

##creating sparse matrix  
row = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]) 
col = np.array([0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1]) 
   
data = np.array([1, 0, 1, 1, float('nan'), 1]) 
   
sparse_matrix = csr_matrix((data, (col, row)), shape = (3, 3)) 
  
  
with pm.Model() as model: 
  
    ## Independent priors 
    alpha = pm.Normal('Person', mu = 0, sigma = 3, shape = (1, sparse_matrix.shape[0])) 
    gamma = pm.Normal('Question', mu = 0, sigma = 3, shape = (sparse_matrix.shape[1], 1)) 
  
    ## Log-Likelihood 
    def logp(obs): 
         
        rasch = tt.nnet.sigmoid(alpha - (gamma - gamma.mean(0))) 
        correct = obs* tt.log(rasch) 
        result = correct 
        return result 
  
    ll = pm.DensityDist('ll', logp, observed = sparse_matrix) 
    trace = pm.sample(cores=-1) 
    trace = trace[250:]
```

I get the following error when I run the code. I want to pass sparse observation matrix with a custom logp function to pymc3's DensityDist function. From the error log I understand that logp returns theano.sparse type and by convention logp should have theano.tensor type. Can someone suggest a way to convert theano.sparse to theano.tensor or any other workaround for this? One of the solutions I found was to convert sparse matrix to dense and then to theano tensor, but my actual data is very big and this solution is not feasible.

Error Log

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_1560/445393482.py in <module>
     28         return result
     29 
---> 30     ll = pm.DensityDist('ll', logp, observed = sparse_matrix)
     31     trace = pm.sample(cores=-1)
     32     trace = trace[250:]
~\anaconda3\envs\confidence_modeling\lib\site-packages\pymc3\distributions\distribution.py in __new__(cls, name, *args, **kwargs)
    120         else:
    121             dist = cls.dist(*args, **kwargs)
--> 122         return model.Var(name, dist, data, total_size, dims=dims)
    123 
    124     def __getnewargs__(self):
~\anaconda3\envs\confidence_modeling\lib\site-packages\pymc3\model.py in Var(self, name, dist, data, total_size, dims)
   1175         else:
   1176             with self:
-> 1177                 var = ObservedRV(
   1178                     name=name,
   1179                     data=data,
~\anaconda3\envs\confidence_modeling\lib\site-packages\pymc3\model.py in __init__(self, type, owner, index, name, data, distribution, total_size, model)
   1829             # The logp might need scaling in minibatches.
   1830             # This is done in `Factor`.
-> 1831             self.logp_sum_unscaledt = distribution.logp_sum(data)
   1832             self.logp_nojac_unscaledt = distribution.logp_nojac(data)
   1833             self.total_size = total_size
~\anaconda3\envs\confidence_modeling\lib\site-packages\pymc3\distributions\distribution.py in logp_sum(self, *args, **kwargs)
    265         if only the sum of the logp values is needed.
    266         """
--> 267         return tt.sum(self.logp(*args, **kwargs))
    268 
    269     __latex__ = _repr_latex_
~\anaconda3\envs\confidence_modeling\lib\site-packages\theano\tensor\basic.py in sum(input, axis, dtype, keepdims, acc_dtype)
   3219     """
   3220 
-> 3221     out = elemwise.Sum(axis=axis, dtype=dtype, acc_dtype=acc_dtype)(input)
   3222 
   3223     if keepdims:
~\anaconda3\envs\confidence_modeling\lib\site-packages\theano\graph\op.py in __call__(self, *inputs, **kwargs)
    248         """
    249         return_list = kwargs.pop("return_list", False)
--> 250         node = self.make_node(*inputs, **kwargs)
    251 
    252         if config.compute_test_value != "off":
~\anaconda3\envs\confidence_modeling\lib\site-packages\theano\tensor\elemwise.py in make_node(self, input)
   1923         # we can infer what dtype should be, and create a node from an Op
   1924         # of the appropriate dtype.
-> 1925         input = as_tensor_variable(input)
   1926         dtype = self._output_dtype(input.dtype)
   1927         acc_dtype = self._acc_dtype(input.dtype)
~\anaconda3\envs\confidence_modeling\lib\site-packages\theano\tensor\basic.py in as_tensor_variable(x, name, ndim)
    145 
    146         if not isinstance(x.type, TensorType):
--> 147             raise TypeError(
    148                 "Tensor type field must be a TensorType; found {}.".format(type(x.type))
    149             )
TypeError: Tensor type field must be a TensorType; found <class 'theano.sparse.type.SparseType'>.
```